# How to use tf.nn.avg_pool to get same results as by tf.reduce_mean

Tags: tensorflow

In the following code, I want to use [tf.nn.avg_pool](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/avg_pool) to get the same results as when I use [tf.reduce_mean](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_mean). But how to fix the parameters of tf.nn.avg_pool to get similar results?

```
input = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,16,16,200]))
filter= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16,16,200,1]))
def depth_conv2d(input):
    return tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(input,filter, strides=[1,4,4,1],padding= 'VALID')

depth_conv_out = depth_conv2d(input)

Relu = tf.nn.relu(depth_conv_out)
avg_pooling = tf.reduce_mean(Relu, reduction_indices=[3], keep_dims=True) 
sess = tf. InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

print("convolution result")
print (depth_conv_out.get_shape())
print ("Relu result")
print (Relu.eval())
print(Relu.get_shape())
print ("Average pooling")
print (avg_pooling.get_shape())
```

Answer (score 1):

While the documentation on [tf.nn.avg_pool](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/avg_pool) doesn't explicitly state whether it supports pooling over batch or channel dimensions, the documentation on [tf.nn.pool](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/pool) (which internally calls `tf.nn.avg_pool` if `pooling_type` is set to `'AVG'`) explicitly states:

> `input`: Tensor of rank N+2, of shape `[batch_size] + input_spatial_shape + [num_channels]` if data_format does not start with "NC" (default), or `[batch_size, num_channels] + input_spatial_shape` if data_format starts with "NC". Pooling happens **over the spatial dimensions only**.

However, you can transpose your tensor of shape `[batch_size, height, width, num_channels]` to, say, `[batch_size, height, num_channels, width]`, perform the average pooling and then transpose it back to original form, like in the following example:

```
input_data = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,16,16,200], mean=10, stddev=10))

# compute mean over channels dimension using tf.reduce_mean
mean = tf.reduce_mean(input_data, reduction_indices=[3], keep_dims=True)

# transpose to [batch_size, height, num_channels, width]
input_t = tf.transpose(input_data, [0,1,3,2])

# get the value of num_channels
num_channels = input_t.get_shape().as_list()[2]

# compute mean using tf.nn.avg_pool
avg = tf.nn.avg_pool(value=input_t,
                      ksize=[1, 1, num_channels, 1],
                      strides=[1, 1, num_channels, 1],
                      padding="SAME")

# transpose back to original form
input_tt = tf.transpose(avg, [0,1,3,2])

sess = tf. InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

avg_value = input_tt.eval()
print("Shape after avg_pool method: %s" % str(avg_value.shape))
# >>> (2, 16, 16, 1)

mean_value = mean.eval()
print("Shape after reduce_mean method: %s" % str(mean_value.shape))
# >>> (2, 16, 16, 1)
```